# How does an item get inserted into a Global secodary index of DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

In DynamoDB given a table with PK: "B" and SK "C" and a GSI with PK "B" (same as primary) and SK "D" (different sort key). when an Item B=1 & C=1 & D=2 is inserted into the table, then I expect a row to be both inserted into the GSI as well because they have the same PK. I only get a row inserted into the table.
So, how does an item get inserted into a GSI? Do i need to reference the GSI index name specifically?

Answer (score 2):

There's no special syntax or command required to add an item to an index. Items with GSI keys are part of the [secondary index](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SecondaryIndexes.html), which is *"stored in its own partition space away from the base table and scales separately from the base table"*.  Items that don't have GSI keys are not.   This is the idea behind the [sparse index](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-indexes-general-sparse-indexes.html) pattern:

> Global secondary indexes are sparse by default. When you create a global secondary index, you specify a partition key and optionally a sort key. Only items in the base table that contain those attributes appear in the index.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the items being inserted meet the GSI's criteria and the projection criteria, those items will be inserted into the GSI automatically by DynamoDB. There is nothing you need to do extra.

Comment: And does the addition to index happen/trigger almost instantly after a new row insertion in original table, or does it take some time (i.e. a batch process?)

Comment: It is nearly instant from item insertion to the base table to it making it to the index. Some things can make it not instant though. For example, if the index is being throttled for whatever reason, it can put backpressure on the base table...basically saying, "I am processing as fast as I can. Please slow down!"